# Verifying CUDA-Capable GPU in Ubuntu

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia

I downloaded and installed CUDA-7.5 and found that instruction that I need to check whether I have a CUDA-Capable GPU.
I did as

```
lin@lin-VirtualBox:/opt/caffe$ sudo update-pciids
Downloaded daily snapshot dated 2015-09-07 03:15:01
```

then why I type

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

nothing comes out.

```
lin@lin-VirtualBox:/opt/caffe$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
lin@lin-VirtualBox:/opt/caffe$
```

I have `NVIDIA graphic card GEFORCE GT750M.`
What could be wrong?
My OS is Ubuntu14.04.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are running in a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) VM (virtual machine) instance.  With a typical VirtualBox setup, the graphics in the VM [is virtualized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139320/enable-graphics-card-in-virtual-box); there is no physical GPU device present in the VM.

As a result, the GPU does not show up when you run `lspci` in the VM.

One possible approach to work around this would be to switch to a "baremetal" config; i.e. load Ubuntu directly on your laptop as the primary (or "host") OS, rather than in  a VM.  The GPU should show up that way.

Another possible approach would be to attempt to use [VirtualBox PCI Passthrough](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202926/how-to-use-nvidia-geforce-m310-on-ubuntu-12-10-running-as-guest-in-virtualbox) to make the GPU "visible" in the VM.  Whether or not this would work in a laptop scenario I don't know; there may be side effects of trying to pass through the laptop GPU to a VM; your laptop hypervisor and any other OS's would not have access to the GPU (or the laptop display) in this situation.  I think there are a number of other requirements and restrictions with this approach.  Your laptop hardware may or may not meet the requirements, and I think it is expected that the host OS uses some specific flavors of linux (kernel); you may have windows as the host OS on your laptop.

In any event, how to configure your machine with VirtualBox and/or PCI Passthrough is not a programming question, and I think is off-topic for SO.  You might try [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or another similar forum, for related questions.

Comment: Thanks @Robert Crovella for sharing knowledge. Most straightforward way is to make Linux to be host OS. Thanks